# Python library for experimenting with compiler optimizations

Tags: python, optimization, compiler-construction

I want to learn about compilers and some optimization techniques, and I thought it would be helpful to do some quick implementations of the algorithms.
Is there a library/framework for Python that can make things easier (like the Natural Language Toolkit) - generating the parse tree, manipulating loops, methods?

I saw that Microsoft Research has a library named Phoenix, but it's intended for C++ and I would like to avoid writing prototypes in C++, it's too much work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no Python module to do what you want. But you can create structures by yourself in Python, or use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) and write your compiler with JIT enabled features in RPython.
If you really want to test some algorithms, I highly recommend you to use [LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/), it is in C++, but is the currently state-of-art platform to experiment such things that you're willing to do. LLVM has a lot of optimizations (where you can learn a lot) and a [nice tutorial](http://www.llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) on how you can implement your own, its API is very simple and clean. There is [bindings](http://code.google.com/p/llvm-py/) for Python too if you want, but only for LLVM 2.6. Give LLVM a try, it's a worth reading and you'll learn a lot with tutorials like [this](http://www.llvm.org/docs/tutorial/).